# mysqld: unrecognized service OVH

Tags: mysql

Debian 32 bit - OVH

When i put this:

```
service apache2 stop && service nginx restart && service mysqld restart
```

i show:

```
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

"Try this command: `service mysql restart`:"

```
stopping mysql database server: mysqld
starting mysql database server: mysqld
checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables...
```

but when i enter on my website i saw: `could not connect to database`

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:
`service mysql restart`

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu based uses "/etc/init.d/mysql" instead "mysqld"